# XML Read specific Node

Tags: asp.net, xml, readxml

I want to read an specific xml node and its value for example

```
<customers>
<name>John</name>
<lastname>fetcher</lastname>
</customer>
```

and my code behind should be some thing like this (I don't know how it should be though):

```
Response.Write(xml.Node["name"].Value)
```

As I said it is just an example because I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic answer:
Assuming "xml" is an XMLDocument, XMLNodeList, XMLNode, etc...

```
Response.Write(xml.SelectSingleNode("//name").innerText)
```

Answer (score 3):

Which version of .NET are you using? If you're using .NET 3.5 and can use LINQ to XML, it's as simple as:

```
document.Descendant("name").Value
```

(except with some error handling!) If you're stuk with the DOM API, you might want:

```
document.SelectSingleNode("//name").InnerText
```

Note that this hasn't shown anything about how you'd read the XML in the first place - if you need help with that bit, please give more detail in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Actually what you suggested is enough for me for now :)

Answer (score 2):

If using earlier versions of the .Net framework, take a look at the [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class first as this is what you'd load the XML string into.  Subclasses like [XMLElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) and [XMLNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) are also useful for doing some of this work.

Answer (score 1):

haven't tried testing it but should point you in the right direction anyway

```
 'Create the XML Document
 Dim l_xmld As XmlDocument
'Create the XML Node
        Dim l_node As XmlNode

            l_xmld = New XmlDocument

            'Load the Xml file
            l_xmld.LoadXml("XML Filename as String")

            'get the attributes
            l_node = l_xmld.SelectSingleNode("/customers/name")

           Response.Write(l_node.InnerText)
```